# Is there a facility to allow Facebook page owners to message fans individiually without having to add them initially as a friend?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Is there a solution for a Facebook page owner to message fans individually - without having to manually add them as a friend and then communicate with them?

If not, is there some code that will automatically add a new fan as a 'friend'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages should (and can) never send an individual message to a specific fan, the fan has to initiate the communication. It would be a major spam and privacy issue.

There is also no code to add someone as a friend, especially not triggered by new fans of a page. You can only open a dialog for a friend request: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/

There are Realtime Updates, but not for fans: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime